# 'pip install minecraft' not working, cannot found file

Tags: python, pip

First off, sorry if this is not the right website, I just do not know where to put this.

Hi there. I was trying to install the package minecraft using pip, but when typing in `pip install minecraft` I got the following error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\Fire\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Fire\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a8vtupb2\\minecraft\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Fire\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a8vtupb2\\minecraft\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\Fire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a8vtupb2\minecraft\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Fire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a8vtupb2\minecraft\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        with open(NOTICE, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Fire\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a8vtupb2\\minecraft\\setup.py\\..\\..\\NOTICE.rst'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've tried uninstalling, and reinstalling python but it still doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the package [on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/minecraft/) under the "minecraft" name, it says:

> This is not a usable Python package, but the name is reserved by
> Microsoft Corporation.

You cannot install this package. If you were looking for a package related to minecraft, [find the package on PyPI first](https://pypi.org/search/?q=minecraft) which will say what to type to install the package.

Comment: Oh i'm dumb. Thank you so much!